# Getting the substring from a certain character in NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

If I have an NSString that is initially:

```
"ABCDE*FGHI"
```

How do I make it turn into

```
"FGHI"
```

In other words, everything from the asterisk onwards is kept.

Likewise, how would I turn it into:

```
"ABCDE"
```

(everything up to the asterisk is kept)

Thanks

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
NSString *myString = @"ABCDE*FGHI"; 
NSArray *myArray = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"*"];
```

- key 0 of myArray will contain @"ABCDE"
- key 1 will contain @"FGHI"

If you want more than one character to be the separator,
use `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet`:

```
NSString *myString = @"ABCDE*FGHI-JKL"; 
NSArray *myArray = [myString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"*-"]];
```

- key 0 of myArray will contain @"ABCDE"
- key 1 will contain @"FGHI"
- key 2 will contain @"JKL"

Comment: It can be done by easier way and when a delimiter is an object of NSString

Answer (score 22):

```
NSString *myString = @"ABCDE*FGHI";
NSString *subString = [myString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(0, [myString rangeOfString: @"*"].location)];
```

Comment: I get these errors when compiling with that code: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'substringWithRange:', implicit declaration of function 'NSRangeMake'

Comment: this is better than the accepted answer as it behaves like the OP requested for input like "AB\*CD\*EF"

Answer (score 9):

```
NSString *myString = @"ABCDE*FGHI";
NSArray *myArray = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"*"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *yourString = @"ABCDE*FGHI";

NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"*"]];

for(int i =0 ; i < array.count ; i++){
    NSLog(@"- %d : %@ \n",i,[array objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

Comment: Can you add some text explaining what this code is doing, and if necessary how to integrate it into existing code?  (eg, inputs, outputs, parameters)  Code blobs without explanation do not make very good Stack Overflow answers.

Comment: This code insert all the words seperated by '*' in muttableArray then show them.